# Is there a way to get list of Tenant objects on the client side?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to extend user account association in dashboard Jaggery module of WSO2 Identity Server 5.1 and want display all of tenants in a option select combo when create new association by associated user authentication.

I would like to know exists any possible solution that i can extract all tenants in an array of Tenant object (Tenant[]) by call a web service stub methods from a web client so as Jaggery file.

appreciate for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `retrieveTenants()` of `TenantMgtAdminService` (WSDL is at https://localhost:9443/services/TenantMgtAdminService?wsdl)  which will give an array of [TenantInfoBean](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-commons/blob/master/components/tenant-mgt-common/org.wso2.carbon.tenant.common/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/stratos/common/beans/TenantInfoBean.java)

Comment: Yes, thank you but i want get this list by user authorization. In real in an associated scenarios when define associated user, for do it, must login with username's/password's associated user that for username i need to identify their tenant that i want display tenants in a select option list from all tenants and user choice your tenant. how to do this?